# Giving a custom model name when training a model via REST with azure Form Recognizer api v2.1

Tags: preview, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I would like to try the feature of giving a custom model a name with REST api v 2.1-preview as announced [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/updates/form-recognizer-v2-1/). Since it is already possible with the labeling tool, there should be a way of doing it with the REST call, shouldn't? I've tried to put `modelName="<mymodelname>"` into the request body, but this didn't work.
I'm using REST api v2.1-preview1 according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/python-train-extract?tabs=v2-1) and haven't found any documentation about that, yet. Maybe there is someone, who found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can include the model name in the JSON POST body:

```json
{
    "source": "https://...",
    "modelName": "My Model",
    "useLabelFile": true
}
```

The Python sample would change to:

```py
body = {
    "source": source,
    "modelName": "my model",
    "sourceFilter": {
        "prefix": prefix,
        "includeSubFolders": includeSubFolders
    },
    "useLabelFile": useLabelFile
}
```

Note that there is currently an issue when assigning a model name when `useLabels` is `false`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I've done before. In the meantime, I realized, that there is a bug, too. During training, the name is assigned to the model. But after the training it vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
modelName: "a new model"
```

in your post request.